# Wrong number with collect package

Tags: numbering, ref, collect

I use the collect package to store the answer code.
When the Problem number is wrong when calling the \includecollection comment.
Please help me correct the below code.[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}
\definecollection{btcol}
\newcounter{cbt}
\newenvironment{bt}{\refstepcounter{cbt}\par\noindent {\bfseries Problem \thecbt}.}{\ignorespaces.}
\newcommand{\loigiai}[1]{
\begin{collect}{btcol}{\par\noindent {\bfseries AP\; \thecbt}.}{}{}{} 
    \begingroup
        #1
    \endgroup
\end{collect}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{bt}
Conntent 1
\loigiai{Answer for Pro.1}
\end{bt}
\begin{bt}
Conntent 2
\loigiai{Answer for Pro.2}
\end{bt}

\includecollection{btcol}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand `\thecbt` before calling the `collect` environment; this is most conveniently done with an auxiliary macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collect}
\definecollection{btcol}
\newcounter{cbt}

\newenvironment{bt}
 {%
  \par
  \noindent\refstepcounter{cbt}{\bfseries Problem \thecbt}.%
 }
 {\unskip.}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\loigiai}[1]{%
  \@bsphack\expandafter\loigiai@aux\expandafter{\expanded{\thecbt}}{#1}\@esphack
}
\newcommand{\loigiai@aux}[2]{%
  \begin{collect}{btcol}{\par\noindent{\bfseries AP\; #1}.}{}{}{} 
    #2%
  \end{collect}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{bt}
Content 1
\loigiai{Answer for Pro.1}
\end{bt}

\begin{bt}
Content 2
\loigiai{Answer for Pro.2}
\end{bt}

\includecollection{btcol}

\end{document}
```

I'd avoid adding an “automatic” period: the code I provide is not really fail safe, because you can't have a blank line before `\loigiai`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: The \loigiai comment also contains another counter, key. Please show me how to expand it. Where can I find the document for these command, using aux file. Thank you very much!